# Survey Database Structure

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, erd

I am building a database to feed into a PowerBI dashboard.

The data is extracted as CSV (SurveyResults) from Survey Monkey which will be loading into the MSSQL database.

The outcome i am after is the ability to provide an Average for each KRA.

The response table has a unique row for each survey response, with each question as a separate column, with a score for a value.

Each Question is assigned a KRA, so i have created the lookup table (Question_KRA).

can someone point me in the right direction in how i can structure the data in order to have a summary table which describes the KRA and the average?

I would like to avoid hard coding in a view, as i would like the ability to add in new questions, with relative ease.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) to transpose the question columns from SurveyResults into rows and then average the KRA values from there. This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2eaf61271757a22ffcdad1cd6a4fda2f) shows an example.

The first query shows the UNPIVOT and the second query shows a dynamically generated SELECT statement that would allow you to add additional question columns without needing to recode the SELECT statement.